# Implement relational operator with arithmetic/bitwise operators

Tags: java, operators

Assuming:

- 32-bit signed integers in two's complement form
- `true` and `false` are integers with values `1` and `0`
- java operators

Can you implement relational operators like `<` and `==` using only arithmetic and bitwise operators?

Comment: Can we assume modern 2's complement arithmetic? No overflow exceptions, sign-extending right shift, rounding towards zero, etc? Also, are we allowed to use unsigned and 64-bit arithmetic?

Comment: @doynax Yes, added that to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick attempt. Signed less-than is messy but possible in 32-bit arithmetic if needed.

```
int32_t cmp_lt(int32_t lhs, int32_t rhs) {
    int64_t tmp = lhs;
    tmp -= rhs;
    tmp >>= 63;
    return tmp & 1;
}

int32_t cmp_eq(int32_t lhs, int32_t rhs) {
    return (cmp_lt(lhs, rhs) | cmp_lt(rhs, lhs)) ^ 1;
}

// 32-bit only version
int32_t cmp_lt32(int32_t lhs, int32_t rhs) {
    int32_t tmp = lhs - rhs;
    // -lhs < +rhs is always true
    tmp |= ~rhs & lhs;
    // +lhs < -rhs is always false
    tmp &= ~rhs | lhs;
    tmp >>= 31;
    return tmp & 1;
}
```

edit: I see that Java was asked for. Not my native language but I believe the regular integer and long types could be substituted for int32_t and int64_t here.

Comment: So the short version would be `((a - b) >> 31) & 1`

Comment: @dtech: For the most part, yes, unfortunately 33-bit arithmetic is needed in case the subtraction overflows. E.g. 0x80000000 - 1 becomes positive whereas 0x80000001 - 1 is still negative. This is why most microprocessors have a special signed-overflow flag.

Comment: Hmm ofcourse, so you'd say this isn't possible when you're restricted to 32-bit signed integers?

Comment: @dtech: No, just a bit messy. I've updated the code with a (possibly naive) direct attempt at fixing up the overflow cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the less than/greater than can be implemented by subtracting one from the other, casting to an unsigned int and then use a bitwise AND with the sign bit, then shift it to the least significant bit.

Equality could be done with a binary NOT on the result of subtracting the two numbers.
Haven't tested these, but used something similar in OpenCL years ago to prevent branching on the GPU.

Example for greater than:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int x = 6;
  int y = 4;
  int diff;
  unsigned int* udiff;
  unsigned int gr;
  unsigned int one = 1;

  diff = x - y;
  udiff = (unsigned int*)&diff;
  gr = (*udiff & (one << 31)) >> 31;

  printf("%d", gr);


}
```

[(codepad)](http://codepad.org/udoNiZfr)

Less than can be done analogously. 
Equality:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int x = 4;
  int y = 4;

  int diff;
  unsigned int* udiff;
  unsigned int eq;

  diff = x - y;
  udiff = (unsigned int*)&diff;

  eq = !(*udiff);

  printf("%d", eq);

}
```

[(codepad)](http://codepad.org/8ZNYTqf1)

Not sure how you can do this in Java, this relies on the fact that you can reinterpret a signed integral value as an unsigned int in C using pointer casting.

Comment: Apparently I'm much too slow for this page. For the record a plain assignment will do in C, the compiler will implicitly cast to an unsigned integer. Oh, and consider the INT_MIN < 1 case.